# Greek polytonic inside (new) Greek text

Tags: greek

Good morning!

I 'm writing an article in (new) Greek and I was trying to write a ancient phrase (ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι) in it. I thought that I have to use `\usepackage[greek.polutoniko]{babel}`, but when I tried the code below everything was ok.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

όπερ έδει δείξαι % (new) Greek

ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι % ancient Greek

\end{document}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Apparently, yes!    As far as I know, this works ok because the ancient and modern characters are different UTF8 code points.  So in Unicode omicron+tonos is not the same as omicron+dasia+oxia.  So provided your font has all the code points you need, then you can use them together.  I think `babel` also sets up the hyphenation rules, but maybe that's not a big deal?

Comment: @Thruston , thank's for the answer! So, why I someone has to install `\usepackage[greek.polutoniko]{babel}`, if `\usepackage[greek]{babel}` is also ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The best way to do this is to load a font with `fontspec` that contains polytonic accents.  With `babel` in either XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can use `\babelfont`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{GFS Didot}

\begin{document}

όπερ έδει δείξαι % (new) Greek

ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι % ancient Greek

\end{document}
```

[image: Polytonic Greek]

Babel also supports the language `polutonikogreek`, so you could insert a `\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}` before the second line if you wanted, but that isn’t actually needed in this example.

You can also do this with `polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures = TeX }

\setmainfont{GFS Didot}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = Common]
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Didot}[
  Ligatures = Common,
  Script = Greek,
  Language = Greek ]

\begin{document}

όπερ έδει δείξαι % (new) Greek

ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι % ancient Greek

\end{document}
```

If you need backwards-compatibility with PDFTeX and legacy NFSS, you will have to use the 8-bit LGR encoding, which supports polytonic Greek:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Not actually used here.

\begin{document}

όπερ έδει δείξαι % (new) Greek

ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι % ancient Greek

\end{document}
```

Comment: ,thank's for your answer! (1) I 'm using pdflatex, so I tried your last solution. (2) The `gfsdidot` has problems with the math mode (I think). For example with the `boldsymbol` or `\ell`, so I use `kerkis`. (3) You are suggesting to use `\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
`, instead of my code? Why? For hyphenation reasons?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας Right, I just picked Didot as an example. I suggested T1 instead of OT1 (and `textcomp`) mainly so you get slightly less-obsolete fonts and their full range of glyphs. I throw in `inputenc` just in case someone tries to compile the document on an old installation.

Answer (score 2):

The option `greek.polutoniko` changes a few things compared to `greek`. E.g. fix names are different. \refname gives with polutoniko

[image]

but this with greek:

[image]

The date format are perhaps also different. The two options load different hyphenation patterns, and the code shows also a few lccode setting -- this could affect \MakeUppercase -- and different shorthands.

But there I see nothing font encoding related, so for short sentences it should be okay, if you have an eye on the hyphenation.

Comment: thank's for your answer! I thought that the hyphenation or the orthography might have problems.